# Individual T-SQL statements run fine individually but not when combined

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of SQL statements that I want to execute to update the schema of a database - they all run fine individually (i.e. when I run them manually one after the other) but I run into issues when I attempt to combine them into a single script, wrapped around some versioning logic.

My script is as follows:

```
DECLARE @VersionCode varchar(20)
DECLARE @Description varchar(50)
DECLARE @Author varchar(20)
DECLARE @AppVersion varchar (10)

SET @VersionCode = 'version code';
SET @Description = 'description';
SET @Author = 'author';
SET @AppVersion = 'app version';

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Version] WHERE [VersionCode] = @VersionCode)
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [Journal] ADD [BreakDurationNew] INT NULL
        UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDurationNew = BreakDuration
        ALTER TABLE [Journal] DROP COLUMN [BreakDuration]
        EXEC sp_rename 'Journal.BreakDurationNew', 'BreakDuration', 'COLUMN';

        -- create triggers on JournalBreak so that BreakDuration on Journal is updated
        CREATE TRIGGER TR_JournalBreak_Insert ON [JournalBreak]
        FOR INSERT
        AS  
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM INSERTED) 
        END

        CREATE TRIGGER TR_JournalBreak_Update ON [JournalBreak]
        FOR UPDATE
        AS  
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM INSERTED)
            UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM DELETED)
        END

        -- insert version record
        INSERT INTO [RG].[dbo].[Version] (VersionCode, Description, Author, AppVersion) VALUES
        (@VersionCode, @Description, @Author, @AppVersion)
    END
END
```

My guess is I've got something (or a bunch of things!) syntactically wrong with my script but I can't spot it currently. Can anyone help please?

cheers!

Comment: You don't have a "feel" for T-SQL yet.  `CREATE TRIGGER`, for instance, needs to be the first command in a batch (or preceded by `GO`).  Hence, you cannot create a trigger conditionally, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff too true! I did see that thing about CREATE TRIGGER when researching this - even when I remove the two CREATE TRIGGER statements, it fails with something innocuous...

Comment: *"it fails with something innocuous..."* > Fails how?

Comment: @TT. sorry for the late response. The error that I get is `'Invalid column name 'BreakDurationNew'` on the line `UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDurationNew = BreakDuration` which almost suggests that it completely ignores the line before it (which adds the new column in)

Comment: Wrap it all in separate Dynamic SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like @GordonLinoff comment

```
DECLARE @VersionCode VARCHAR(20) = 'version code'
DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(50) = 'description'
DECLARE @Author VARCHAR(20) = 'author'
DECLARE @AppVersion VARCHAR(10) = 'app version'
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(Max) = ''

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM [Version]
            WHERE [VersionCode] = @VersionCode
            )
    BEGIN
        SET @CMD = 'ALTER TABLE [Journal] ADD [BreakDurationNew] INT NULL'
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD

    SET @CMD = 'UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDurationNew = BreakDuration

    ALTER TABLE [Journal] DROP COLUMN [BreakDuration]'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD

    EXEC sp_rename 'Journal.BreakDurationNew','BreakDuration','COLUMN';

    -- create triggers on JournalBreak so that BreakDuration on Journal is updated
    SET @CMD = '
    CREATE TRIGGER TR_JournalBreak_Insert ON [JournalBreak]
    FOR INSERT
    AS  
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM INSERTED) 
    END'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD

    SET @CMD = '
    CREATE TRIGGER TR_JournalBreak_Update ON [JournalBreak]
    FOR UPDATE
    AS  
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM INSERTED)
        UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDuration = (coalesce([dbo].[CalculateJournalBreak]([JournalId]),(0))) WHERE [JournalId] IN (SELECT JournalId FROM DELETED)
    END
    '

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @CMD

    -- insert version record
    INSERT INTO [RG].[dbo].[Version] (VersionCode, Description, Author, AppVersion) VALUES
    (@VersionCode, @Description, @Author, @AppVersion)
END
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's still not working for me however. The error that I get is `'Invalid column name 'BreakDurationNew'` on the line `UPDATE [Journal] SET BreakDurationNew = BreakDuration` which almost suggests that it completely ignores the line before it (which adds the new column in) - similar to when I simply remove the `CREATE TRIGGER` commands

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are attempting to invent some kind of patch mechanism. I'd suggest to produce separate scripts:

1. some script that will check which version you have on specific server and will decide whether to run real *patch script* or not
2. straightforward "stupid" patch script with all DDL and DML statements (with GO separator where needed) applicable to determined version

So my suggestion is to develop a flow-control tool, give it a feature to determine which version is on the server and another feature - send appropriate patch script to `sqlcmd.exe`. And probably check for errors if any. This could be even a batch file (*.cmd).